# using history command in bash with ssh and getting output with time stamps

Tags: bash, ssh, unix, history

Basically i want to get a record of all commands executed on my ssh server, with their times.
The codes i have tried are :

```
ssh user@ip 'export HISTFILE=~/.bash_history; set -o history; history'
```

I got all commands,but i dont get time stamps with this which is expected i guess.

When i first login and then use history command, i get all details including date and time. I would like to get all details when i use history command with ssh. How should i go about it?
OH yeah, and if possible i would like to get the history without needing to export HISTFILE.(IF POSSIBLE)
**Installing packages is not an option.**

Comment: Without using histfile my command gives no output

Comment: Check here for the solution. http://superuser.com/questions/962001/incorrect-output-of-history-command-of-ssh-how-to-read-the-timestamp-info-corre

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. You need to also export e.g.

   ```
   HISTTIMEFORMAT='%F %T '
   ```

   to set display command history times.
2. If you have *not* set the `HISTTIMEFORMAT` environment variable when using a session, the command times will *not* be saved and you will then of course not be able to see them. By default the current time will be printed as the command time for every command lacking a time indicator.

If you look at the `~/.bash_history` file you can see if you have had time stamps activated for the sessions. Every other line will then start with a `#` followed by the [epoch time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) of the next command.

Comment: 1180  05/14/12-15:59:32 #1336971016

1181  05/14/12-15:59:32 ssh root@172.19.66.137
How can i remove the line with #1336971016. it comes after every command 
@Daniel Andersson

Comment: @ganducoder: I can't really see the formatting in the comment field. You could pipe the output to `grep -v "^#"` to remove all lines that start with a `#` (if  you want to remove a complete line). This is the time stamp field in epoch time, as I described in my post.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the shell to be `bash` and the history file to be `.bash_history` a simple fetch should suffice.

`scp user@ip:.bash_history .`

For the time data,

- The `.bash_history` file will carry time information from the history data of all sessions that were running with a `HISTTIMEFORMAT` configured
- I think the history update will carry timestamps for the entire session that had a `HISTTIMEFORMAT` configuration at any time within it
- Which brings us to a small constraint

  - if you have the `bash profile` for these remote user logins with the
    `export HISTTIMEFORMAT='some format'`, you are good with just pulling the `.bash_history` file
  - else, running the remotely history command in any form is not going to get you the time data -- simply because it is not stored (to `.bash_history`) in the first place; it is lost at the end of each session and only the command list is saved

Hope the last point clarifies feasibility of getting time data.
The good news is, if you can see the time data for past sessions when you login, it is configured and you don't need any change. If not, it is just a matter of inserting the `export`  in the `bash profile` being used -- no installations required.